Growth of distance between divergent hyperbolic lines is at least linear in the arc-length parameter
I'm trying to do Chapter 3 Problem 21 in
Geometry and Topology (Reid M., Szendroi B.) 2005 ed.

The hyperbolic plane ${\cal H}^2=\{(t,x,y):t^2-x^2-y^2=1,t>0\}$
WLOG let $L_1$ be the hyperbolic line $\{y=0\}$.
$P(s)=(\cosh s, \sinh s, 0)$ is a parametrization of $L_1$ by arc-length $s$ in Minkowski metric.
I need to choose $L_2$ such that $L_1\cap L_2$ is empty. Equivalently, the intersection of the plane through $O,L_1$ and the plane through $O,L_2$ intersect is a line of $\Bbb R^3$ that doesn't intersect ${\cal H}^2$.
Example 1
Taking the x-axis $\{t=y=0\}$ as the intersection of the two planes
So $L_2$ is of the form $\frac{t}{\cosh(a)}=\frac{y}{\sinh(a)}$ for some $a$.
$P'(s)=(\cosh(s)\cosh(a),\sinh(s),\cosh(s)\sinh(a))$ is a parametrization of $L_2$ by arc-length $s$ in Minkowski metric.
Then
$$d(P(s),P'(s))=\cosh^{-1}(-P(s)\cdot_L P'(s))=\cosh^{-1}(\cosh^2(s)\cosh(a)-\sinh^2(s))\\=\cosh^{-1}(1+\cosh^2(s)(\cosh(a)-1))$$
so$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{d(P(s),P'(s))}s=2$$
Example 2
Taking the line of $\Bbb R^3$ $$\{t=x,y=0\}$$ as the intersection of the two planes.
So $L_2$ is of the form $y=k(t-x)$ for some $k$.
Plugging $y=k(t-x)$ into $t^2-x^2-y^2=1$, I get $(t-x)(t+x-k^2(t-x))=1$
Solving $\cases{t+x-k^2(t-x)=e^{-s}\\t-x=e^s}$ I get $(t,x,y)=(\frac{k^2+e^{-2s}+1}{2}e^s,\frac{k^2+e^{-2s}-1}{2}e^s,ke^s)$.
I verified $-(\frac{dt}{ds})^2+(\frac{dx}{ds})^2+(\frac{dy}{ds})^2=1$
Then $P'(s)=(\frac{k^2+e^{-2s}+1}{2}e^s,\frac{k^2+e^{-2s}-1}{2}e^s,ke^s)$ is a parametrization of $L_2$ by arc-length $s$ in Minkowski metric.
$$d(P(s),P'(s))\\=\cosh^{-1}(-P(s)\cdot_L P'(s))\\=\cosh^{-1}\left(\cosh(s)\frac{k^2+e^{-2s}+1}{2}e^s-\sinh(s)\frac{k^2+e^{-2s}-1}{2}e^s\right)\\=\cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{k^2}{2}+\cosh (2 s)\right)$$
so$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{d(P(s),P'(s))}s=2$$
Question:
In the above two examples, if my calculation is correct, the limit is both $2$.
Is this limit always $2$?
Thanks.

Let $b$ be the length of common perpendicular of two diverging lines.
Using a formula for Saccheri quadrilateral:
$$\sinh\left(\tfrac {1}{2}d(P(s),P'(s))\right)=\cosh(s)\,\sinh({\tfrac {1}{2}}b)$$
Since $b$ is constant,
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{\frac12d(P(s),P'(s))}{s}=\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{\sinh^{-1}\left(\cosh(s)\,\sinh({\tfrac {1}{2}}b)\right)}{s}=1$$
we get
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{d(P(s),P'(s))}{s}=2$$

